# Suppress DLL messages or callback function

Tags: delphi

I plan to use https://github.com/risoflora/brookframework as an embedded static server in a Delphi application. It requires https://github.com/risoflora/libsagui and seems very fast. But I can't find an option to suppress messages coming from the libsagui DLL.

A common scenario is when the desired port can't be bound, I prefer to get an exception or some error handler callback, rather than get a MessageBox which can't be controlled by my application.

Any info or suggestion?

Comment: Seems like this is something you should be asking the framework author about.

Comment: sure, but on github question page he wrote, to question it on here :) and maybe someone already solve this :D

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to take a flying leap here and just toss out what occurs to me at the moment. First, DLLs are not supposed to have ANY sort of UI activity. If someone does that deliberately and not because they just don't know, then it usually signals there's a serious problem afoot in the run-time activity.

Second, assuming that this signals a serious problem, then there's likely to be some mechanism in place to avoid it. This is for an embedded situation, so one might ask "why can't a desired port be bound" if the person doing the embedding is also responsible for configuring the overall embedded environment? One does not leave things undefined or unconfigured in embedded situations or the application just blows up at some point. So the obvious question is, why are YOU (as the person who configured the embedded environment) writing code that's trying to connect to unavailable ports? And why are YOU also complaining that the underlying library isn't throwing an exception rather than throwing up its virtual hands saying it doesn't know how to handle a request YOUR CODE should have known better than to make?

In other words, if you feel the need to add a layer to your code between your app and the platform you configured to support it, in order to validate your own requests, then you're free to do so. Otherwise, I'm guessing the embedded library designer expects you to know the limits you configured into it. (Or there may be some he did not anticipate.)

I've done a lot of embedded programming in my past, and if I was using a configurable kernal that I configured to only support 10 tasks (because I knew my application didn't need more than that), then in my client code I'd do a check to ensure that said limit wasn't reached BEFORE creating a new task and expecting to get an exception back if I was too stupid to follow my own design guidelines. In embedded situations, "exceptions" can lead to auto-shutdown or even self-destruct sequences. There is no effective way to handle "exceptions" in real-time situations, and often even just embedded situations.

Imagine pushing on a brake pedal in a car and an exception is thrown -- the user is saying "slow down" and the library says, "Sorry, I can't do that right now". It's shades of "2001 A Space Odyssy" with HAL telling Dave "No". That's what "exceptions" in embedded systems can result in.

What's different between that and your app saying, "Connect to this URL via this port" and the underlying library saying, "Sorry I can't do that right now". What is your exception handling code going to do? You need to detect that stuff FIRST rather than wait for an exception to be thrown by the embedded library.

Finally, this is more of a rant than anything else ... but one thing I've found sorely lacking in the vast majority of open-source projects on github I've looked at is any clear explanation of one or more USE-CASE MODELS. In this situation, WHY did the author choose to design this embedded DLL so it has situations where it simply throws up its hands by displaying an error message in a low-level MessageBox rather than providing some mechanism for handling the issue more elegantly? Obviously, he had SOMETHING in mind when he did that. Unfortunately for us, he did not explain it anywhere. Here we are trying to figure out how to deal with something that, on its face, makes no sense -- a DLL throwing up its hands when faced with an exceptional situation.

So my answer is, in the "spirit" of open-source code repos, you're free to dig into the code and try to figure out the USE-CASE MODEL that the author had in mind when he created this thing, and adapt your code to fit that model. Maybe start by looking at examples of code he posted that use this library, although if they're your typical trival examples people often post, then they won't offer a lot of insight into the overall USE-CASE MODEL that is leading to your situation.

Said another way, assume the library is behaving "as designed". Then WHAT IS THIS LIBRARY EXPECTING YOU TO DO IN YOUR CODE IN ORDER TO AVOID THAT SITUATION FROM ARISING?

Hopefully someone will see this who has a much shorter definitive answer to that.

Comment: As you mentioned on first, I expect, that a dll work silently, and give the controll of the problems to a higher level. In this exact scenario, the open-and-try-another-if-failed method cheaper, then the check-the-port-and-start-if-free way.

So I create the port rotation in higher level, but it will be handy if the port checking work remain the dll. Are there a reason, thet my port check soultution assumes the port is free, but the dll also can't bind to thet, for any other reason. Thats why I like tha way, when I can catch this sigan, end decide what to to, try a nother port, or other

Comment: @NemoPeti I'm not doing to do your work for you. If the DLL's author just threw in some UI messages because he doesn't realize they don't belong there, then I would not trust the rest of the DLL. Otherwise, they basically serve as "fire alarms" and they were the best thing the author could think of. You're going to have to figure this out and determine if the fault is in the DLL or your own code. If the author tells you to post your question here rather than dig into it himself, I think that I'd just avoid the thing entirely since he does not seem clear about his own code.